# stringstream << operator doesnot work with Macro with C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, gnu

We have some Macros like

```
#define LOGG(out,line,file,.....)
    std::stringstream logprocess;  \
    logprocess << std::stringstream(out) ;                \
    functiona(out,....,....);
}
```

So the thing to be passed to LOGG can be like:

```
LOGG(message<<"i would like to print"<<interger,......)
```

So we mainly use "<<" to constructor from whater ever type we want and then send to the MACRO LOGG. It works perfect with gnuc++ 98 but we it is compiled with -std=c++11, it gives error:

error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::stringstream {aka std::basic_stringstream}' and 'std::stringstream {aka std::basic_stringstream}')

Comment: Death to MACRO! Use an `inline` function. It will scope the variables correctly and allow you to debug the logger much, much more easily.

Comment: The error message is very clear. There's no such overload for the `<<` operator. Pretty sure there was no such overload prior to C++11 either, so either you are mistaken, it was a compiler bug, or a compiler extension; but in any case without a [mcve] it's not possible to provide an answer. You need to edit your question and provide a [mcve] instead of random code fragments that won't even compile for many other reasons.

Comment: inline function cannot get the line number I think.

Comment: @user45 Unfortunately, macros are still required for some logging and debugging tasks, such as convenient use of `__LINE__`, `__FILE__` and similar.

Comment: @ Sam Varshavchik We indeed use GNUC++ not the std c++, but I shall be able to check GNUC++ somehow, still trying to find it

Comment: But... you didn't use those macros in your logging function....

Comment: Also, please ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as @thundium pointed out, the error message is pretty clear.
An std::stringstream cannot accept an std::stringstream using it's << operator. Maybe you could use this instead:

```
logprocess << std::stringstream(out).str()
```

But I won't recommend it.

I can't say for sure how exactly you use this macro in your code, but I do spot a few possible improvements, for example:

- Why does your macro receive file and line as parameters? This is a macro and it can use the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` inherently
- Why create two string streams when one is sufficient?
- Why have an additional functional wrapper around the actual logging facility and not just use std::cout or std::ofstream?

Here are two simple and trivial implementations I think you can use in your code with minimum adjustments:

```
#define LOGG1(...) \
    std::cout << __FILE__ << "[" << __LINE__ << "] " <<  __VA_ARGS__ << "\n"

#define LOGG2(...) \
    std::stringstream ss; \
    ss << __FILE__ << "[" << __LINE__ << "] " <<  __VA_ARGS__ << "\n"; \
    functional(ss.str());
```

Here is a [full example](https://pastebin.com/s0cqcSU1)